# When deserializing with GSON, how can I determine which fields were not sent in the raw JSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a data structure class and incoming `JSON` data.  I use the `fromJson(jsonData, MyClass)` method to deserialize the data into the class.  The incoming `JSON` data varies and sometimes certain values are not sent.

I would like to be able to determine which values are not sent from those that are sent but specifically set to `null`.  Initializing the fields in my data structure class does not seem to help because even if they are not sent in the raw `JSON` data, they are set to null during the `fromJson()` method it seems.  I also could not seem to get this to work with a deserialization exclusion strategy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to determine? You want to know exactly which fields were missing from the incoming JSON data? If they are null in the resulting object instance, you can assume they were either missing, or had null values. Is this not enough?

Comment: No, that's not enough.  Some values are sent with null which is a valid value for setting information elsewhere.  If a value is not sent in the JSON (it still exists in the data structure and is set to null) I do NOT want to use that value for setting any information.  Basically, if a value comes through as null, I'm setting a database field to null; but if a value does not come through, I do not want to overwrite that database field with null.

Comment: In my initial go at this, I tried setting my fields in the data structure to some value (e.g. String x = "<NOT SET>";) (i.e. a non-null value), but this seems to be overwritten to null when using the fromJson() method.  I am hoping to find a way to convince GSON to leave those values alone or something else along those lines.  I'd rather not have to parse the JSON, determine which fields were sent, determine which fields are in the data structure, and then set those fields after the fact to some non-null value so that I can later determine that they were not sent in the interface.

Comment: Looking into this further, it seems that it is due to the fields being contained in another structure : 

[{
  "A":{
    "B": "value",
    "C": "value"
  }
}]

I have a value "D" on the same level as "B" & "C" in my data structure.  I tested with a value on the same level as "A" and it maintained it's original value.  I'm going to take a closer look at the data structure itself and see if I can't tweak it to get the results I'd like to see.

Comment: Apparently I can't answer my own question for 8 hours, but here is the solution :

Changing the inner classes in my data structure to static solved my problem.  The fields maintained their original value if they were not sent in the JSON.

Comment: @user1984498 You are right, you should answer your question yourself. One thing more, Objects other than strings don't get initialized even by marking inner classes static. We have to initialize them in default constructors.

Comment: This seems to still be an open issue: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/513